# Random acces to matrix using seed in Java

Tags: java, random, seed

How can I access `matrix` (`int[][] matrix`) using random (with seed)?

I want to print my `matrix` randomly.

How to use `seed` and `random` methods? Can you give me a example?

`Seed` **is important**.
I want to write everything only once.

```
int[][] matrix = ini();
 // print matrix randomly using seed...?
```

Comment: `how can i acces to matrix` What matrix? Where's the code? Do you mean random from the Random class?

Comment: I mean matrix of int: `int[][] matrix`. Yes, Random class - or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the seed of the Random instance

```
Random rand = new Random(seed);
```

You can get an inclusive random value by calling the nextInt method...

```
int row = rand.nextInt(matrix.length);
```

...and use these values to access the matrix:

```
int val = matrix[row][otherRandomValue];
```

To print the matrix randomly, you will need to loop over the length of the row and column. To avoid duplicate values, you can keep a Set of indexes (such as using the java.awt.Point class) and check this set to see if the value has been used yet

```
Set<Point> uniques = new HashSet<Point>();

for ( int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++ ){//loop over rows
    for ( int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++ ){
        Point p = new Point(rand.nextInt(matrix.length), rand.nextInt(matrix[i].length));
        while ( uniques.contains(p) ){
            p = new Point(rand.nextInt(matrix.length), rand.nextInt(matrix[i].length));
        }
        uniques.add(p);
        //p.x and p.y contain the indexes
    }
}
```

Comment: Then loop over the matrix. There are plenty of examples for doing this online, and I edited my response with a small abbreviated snipped of a loop

Comment: I think OP doesn't want to print the same row/column index twice.

Comment: It does not guarantee me a listing of all , or duplication.

Comment: @Stefan: yes, true, i don't want print same index twice times.

Comment: Including information like that is important in getting the answer you seek.

Comment: See edit, which uses a Set to check for unique values

Comment: @copeg: Thank you very much copeg, its nice. It work. Thank you.